# Singleton decorator in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, singleton, decorator

I'm trying to use this code:

```
function singleton<T extends { new() }>(constructor: T): T {
    return new constructor()
}

@singleton
export default class SomeClass {
    constructor() {}

    public method(): string {
        return 'Hello!'
    }
}

console.log(SomeClass.method())
```

And it works. The message "Hello!" is displayed in the console. But the typescript compiler says there's error: [image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Probably the compiler does not expect a decorator to change the type of a `class` to that of an object. And he's in good company there - you shouldn't do this. To write singletons, use `const SomeClass = { public method(): string {
        return 'Hello!'
    }
};` and be done with it!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the compiler cannot know what changes the  decorator  does to the class. You could try something like this:

```
function singleton<T>(constructor: new ()=> T): T {
    return new constructor()
}

export const SomeClass = singleton(class  {
  constructor() {}

  public method(): string {
      return 'Hello!'
  }
});

console.log(SomeClass.method())
```

Comment: @ Titian Cernicova-Dragomir I have a doubt  how to pass a value in the constructor using singleton class

Comment: @hariprasanth someting like this could work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxmA5gGwKZQQHgBUBhTAQ2WUWwA8pswATKsbAd0QAoA6XsgLkRkwATwDaAXQCUAXgB8Q0XM4QEyKACcQ0OBsElylADSJe3AYmJrN2vBoAKZDWQC2ubBuRFSFZHKmCAJJg6sIQ2IQiAA7Y3oZ+iADeAFCIaYgauCAaSKwcqiE2OhqcUskAvsnJtFG6UIgF6ogAynBuPpSIMihoWLgIKvFJqQ3WWsWcFmAgLgBGHlJJlSNRILOYMBCIblAAFnCMpYLqGr3D6emZUNlIAOQAEtiYmHAAhLcjleUmAIwADFIANxVRpwHDcF7oTitdrxbg7faHKRSIA

Answer (score 0):

Just use `new` before your class declaration:

```
export default new class {
  constructor() {}

  public method(): string {
      return 'Hello!'
  }
});
```